# How to get the LanguageConfiguration for the current document in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In Visual Studio Code, how I get a [`LanguageConfiguration`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#LanguageConfiguration) object for the language in the current document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is currently not possible. There's an open feature request here: [#2871](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2871)